# Define a method with generic param of type M<T> in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am struggling on how to do this:
I am trying to have the DoSomething method accept all classes which are derived from GenericClass < T > without having to dismantle the GenericDerived class to < GenericDerived, Base >.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass.DoSomething<GenericDerived>(new GenericDerived()); //Still not compiler friendly
    }
}

class Base { }

class GenericClass<T> where T : Base { }

class GenericDerived : GenericClass<Base> { }

class SomeClass
{
    public static void DoSomething<M, B>(M instance)
        where B : Base
        where M : GenericClass<B>
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: CLR [does not support](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2228766-add-higher-order-generics-to-f-type-classes) [higher-kinded types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_%28type_theory%29), so you can't parametrize a type with other, already parametrized type, if that's what you're asking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a type parameter named T in your example. You need to add it and its constraints too.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething<M,T>(M instance) where T : Base 
                                             where M : GenericClass<T>
    {
       // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't know why I missed that...feeling stupid..lol. Will accept your answer if a few minutes

Comment: @Nims It happens to us all :)

Comment: @Nims - You need to provide both generic parameters at the call site i.e. `SomeClass.DoSomething<GenericDerived, Base>(new GenericDerived());`

Comment: @Lee thanks - but is there no way to somehow pass a type M<T> in and make sure that ( M : GenericClass<T> and T : Base ) without having to dismantle the class for this method when it's called?

Comment: @Nims - There's no way to partially specify generic type parameters, you have to give them all if the compiler cannot infer them. You could move the type `T` to the enclosing class, then you could do `SomeClass<Base>.DoSomething(new GenericDerived());`

Comment: @Lee Thanks again...wish the compiler could infer something like this: public static void DoSomething<M<B>>(M instance)
            where B : Base
            where M : GenericClass<B>